# WPF textbox textChanged event not triggered when deleting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a Visual Studio plugin project. I found a very weird problem with my textbox in the WPF window.

When there is no code files opened in the Visual Studio, both typing in and deleting in textbox are fine. But when there is a code file opened in the Visual Studio, I can only type into the textbox. Pressing "backspace" will delete text in the code file even if the textbox has the focus. When pressing the "backspace", the textChanged event is not fired

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxSearch" 
DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10" Width="400" BorderThickness="0" 
TextChanged="textBoxSearch_TextChanged" Focusable="True" />
```

C#:

```
private string reportPath = null;
private IEnumerable<CaiasResult> resultCollection;
CollectionView resultCollectionView;

public resultWindow(IEnumerable<CaiasResult> resultCollection, string reportPath)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.reportPath = reportPath;
    //this.DataContext = this;
    this.resultCollection= resultCollection;
    listViewResults.ItemsSource = resultCollection;
    CollectionView resultView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listViewResults.ItemsSource);
    resultView.Filter = ResultFilter;
}

private bool ResultFilter(object item)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxSearch.Text))
        return true;
    else
        return ((item as CaiasResult).info.IndexOf(textBoxSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}

private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listViewResults.ItemsSource).Refresh();

}
```

Comment: Using a binding with a property changed notification!  Events are sooooooooo WinForms =P

Comment: Tried restarting your VS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this event : ***PreviewKeyDown***